# Add icon controls to rich:panel

Tags: richfaces

I wanted to add icon controls to the header of rich:panel, is it possible to add such controls.

I meant something like close icon, settings icon to header of panel as we could do to modal panel.

I tried it the same way, but the icons were not placed in the header. Also wanted to I cant use rich:componentControl for those icons as

rich:componentControl is used only for JS functions.

Is it by any ways possible to place the icone in rich:panel header and invoke bean methods?

Regards,

Satya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set panel header using `<f:facet/>` tag.

Example:

```
<rich:panel id="myPanel">
  <f:facet name="header">
    <a4j:commandLink id="myPanelControl" value="Control"/>
  </f:facet>

  My panel content. 
</rich:panel>
```

If you want to "close" (you mean hide?) the panel, you can use jQuery

**Example with JQuery:**

```
<a4j:commandLink onclick="$('#myPanel').hide();"/> <!-- Or show(); -->
```

**Using display:**

```
document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = 'none' //Or 'block' to show it back
```

**Using `<rich:componentControl/>`**, but its not necessary (in this case, with a `<a4j:commandLink/>`)..

```
<rich:componentControl for="myPanelControl" event="onclick" operation="use jQuery or display here.."/>
```

If you want to execute a bean method with a h:graphicImage, use `rich:componentControl` with just `action` and `onComplete`:

```
<rich:componentControl event="onclick" action="#{...}" onComplete="hide script here"/>
```

Or you can nest a image inside a `<a4j:commandLink/>`

```
<a4j:commandLink id="myPanelControl" action="#{myBean.executeSomething} value="" onComplete="$('#myPanel').hide()">
   <h:graphicImage value="/myImage.jpg"/>
</a4j:commandLink>
```

More info about the panel can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_panel.html) and [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/panel.jsf?c=panel&tab=usage).